# Extract session ID from response header

Tags: regex

How do I extract the JSESSIONID (everything after '=' and before ';' from this ResponseHeader?

```
Set-Cookie:Apache=40.76.87.14.1462996905538733; path=/; domain=.cra-arc.gc.ca,JSESSIONID=KjahaS5VdMBttn9bAYuS_iHFXOgmqQyMxHcht1kBS7p1YOpdV2V_!1094217526; path=/; HttpOnly
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
/JSESSIONID=(.*?);/
```

---

**Regex101 Demo:**

https://regex101.com/r/nH4mT0/1

---

**Regex Explanation:**

```
JSESSIONID=(.*?);

Match the character string “JSESSIONID=” literally (case sensitive) «JSESSIONID=»
Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 1 «(.*?)»
   Match any single character that is NOT a line break character (line feed, carriage return, line separator, paragraph separator) «.*?»
      Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy) «*?»
Match the character “;” literally «;»
```

Comment: Oh this is neat too! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use this pattern:

```
/JSESSIONID=([^;]*)/
```

Explaining the above regex:

```
JSESSIONID=           # match the text literally
(                     # asserts that all content inside it will be in group $1
    [^;]                  # means any character not ';'
    *                     # as many as possible
)                     # end of the group $1
```

Your desired value will be inside group 1.

You can see it in [action here](https://regex101.com/r/wM0jP7/1).

Comment: thank you! I guess I can just split the string at the '=' with JS as it still captures the entire group from JSESSIONID all the way to the just before the semicolon.

Comment: Yes, you can ;)... As you said now it is JS, my answer would be: `var result = string.match(/JSESSIONID=([^;]*)/)[1];`